# Detecting calendar up/down scroll in FPT MaterialControls Calendar

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I am using FPT Material Control Calendar in my Xamarin iOS app. The calendar is having the scrolling functionality (Up and Down) and the month is also changing in the calendar view. I have added a view and set MDCalendar as class in the interface builder which is the "calendarView"

`calendarView.Theme = MDCalendarTheme.Light;
 calendarView.Delegate = new CalendarSource();`

The `CalendarSource` contains the delegate method `DidSelectDate(MDCalendar calendar, NSDate date)`

**CalendarSource.cs**

```
public class CalendarSource : MDCalendarDelegate
{
    public CalendarSource()
    {
    }

    public override void DidSelectDate(MDCalendar calendar, NSDate date)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(date);
    }
}
```

I am having trouble with detecting the scroll of the calendar. I cannot find any Delegate method for detecting the scroll. Does anyone have an idea of doing this?

Comment: What do you mean when you say detecting the scroll, are you simply referring to an event that would be fired when the scrolling is occurring, or when the scroll ends/starts, or scroll position?

Comment: Yes, I am referring to an event that would be fired when the scrolling is occurring

Comment: I've had a quick look at the github project, and I can't see that the creator has exposed any of the events that you'd expect to be associated with the UICollectionView that they seem to be deriving part of the control from, you can see for yourself at this link https://github.com/fpt-software/Material-Controls-For-iOS/blob/master/MaterialControls.Xamarin.Binding/ApiDefinition.cs  Is it a delegate class that you've created? if so could we see a bit more of the code.

Comment: I have added the calendar source class. Pls have a look at the update

Comment: Unfortunately according to the source code the developer of the control has only exposed the DidSelectDate method as part of the interface MCCalendarDelegate, so I don't think there is an easy way to link into the scroll event in this instance, I'd suggest perhaps posting this question on https://github.com/fpt-software/Material-Controls-For-iOS/issues  this is the 'issues' section of the control your using. Hopefully one of the contributors will get back to you.

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt Thanks a lot for the help. I will raise an issue in their repository.